# Swift iOS мне требуется подтянуть то, что сохраняется в CoreData

Tags: swift

В общем приложение погоды, есть один контроллер в котором вводишь город, и есть соответственно другой, в котором есть таблица с отображением Города и его погоды и т.д. Никак не могу совместить CoreData с пирсингом в таблицу, буду весьма признателен в помощи [image: Контроллер с таблицей]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: [Здесь все прекрасно показано как это сделать!](https://cocoacasts.com/populate-a-table-view-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift-3)[1]